# Python: How do I prevent delayed expansion in the QTimer.singleShot(..) function?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I often use the `QTimer.singleShot(..)` function to execute a certain action/function with some delay. Sure, I could do it with a `time.sleep(..)` as well, but that would freeze my user interface.

Sometimes you want to hand over a parameter to the delayed function. That's where the `lambda` feature of Python comes in handy. Take a look at the following example:

```
    #######################################
    #   Print 'Hello world' vertically    #
    #######################################
    myString = 'Hello world'
    i = 0
    for c in myString:
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10 + i*100, lambda: print(str(c)))
        i += 1
```

One would intuitively expect the output shown on the left. But you actually get a vertical list of character 'd' - which is (surprise) the last character in the given string.

```
         _                                _
    H     |                          d     |
    e     |                          d     |
    l     |                          d     |
    l     |                          d     |
    o     |   Result you             d     |   Result you
           >  would expect           d      >  actually get!
    w     |                          d     |
    o     |                          d     |
    r     |                          d     |
    l     |                          d     |
    d     |                          d     |
         _|                               _|
```

It seems like the `QTimer.singleshot(..)` function applies the 'delayed expansion' principle. That's great in some situations, but not always.

How do you get control over the expansion? Can you force immediate expansion?

---

**Example code :**

Copy-paste the following code into a fresh python file, and run it from the shell.

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

    class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

            # create button
            self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("QTimer.singleShot(..)", self)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.btnAction)
            self.button.resize(200, 30)


        def btnAction(self):
            myString = 'Hello world'
            i = 0
            for c in myString:
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10 + i*100, lambda: print(str(c)))
                i += 1


    def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        form = MainForm()
        form.show()
        app.exec_()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

You will see the 'Hello world' example in your shell when you click the button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The `functools.partial(..)` library allows you to do exactly the same as with the `lambda:..` feature, except that the arguments get freezed :-)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import functools



class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        # create button
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("QTimer.singleShot(..)", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btnAction)
        self.button.resize(200, 30)


    def btnAction(self):
        myString = 'Hello world'
        i = 0
        for c in myString:
            #QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10 + i*100, lambda: print(str(c)))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10 + i * 100, functools.partial(print, str(c)))
            i += 1


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**EDIT :**

Thank you @ekhumoro for your comment. Your code line works as well:

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10 + i*100, lambda arg=c: print(str(arg)))
```

Comment: `lambda arg=c: print(str(arg))`.